# Dynamic Power Calculation in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I have managed to translate the following function in R:

```
p=pwr.2p2n.test(
h=ES.h(conversion_rate_test, conversion_rate_control), 
n1=total_group_size*(1-holdout), 
n2=total_group_size*holdout, 
sig.level=0.1, 
alternative="two.sided")
```

into Python:

```
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms     
es = sms.proportion_effectsize(conversion_rate_test, conversion_rate_control)
sms.NormalIndPower().solve_power(es, nobs1=n1, alpha=alpha, ratio=n2/n1, alternative='two-sided')
```

However, all inputs for calculation in Python are hard encoded now:

```
lift = 0.01
conversion_rate_control = 0.151169
conversion_rate_test = conversion_rate_control*(1+lift)
holdout = 0.01
n1 = 38820.0*(1-holdout)
n2 = 38820.0*holdout
cl = 0.9
alpha = 1-cl
```

The calculation works, yet it needs to be done dynamically, based on the following arrays instead of encoded values:

```
# providing arrays of values for future heatmap
holdout=np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5])
lift=np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4])
```

As a result, I am aiming to build the following heatmap:

[image]

Current calculation in Python generates the output in the bottom left cell of the heatmap.

Please help me take this off, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very similar to R, first we make a data.frame that captures the combinations of holdout / lift, and also a function for the testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
import seaborn as sns

def expand_grid(data_dict):
    rows = itertools.product(*data_dict.values())
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=data_dict.keys())

def test(holdout,lift):
    conversion_rate_control = 0.151169
    conversion_rate_test = conversion_rate_control*(1+lift)
    es = sms.proportion_effectsize(conversion_rate_test, conversion_rate_control)
    n1 = 38820.0*(1-holdout)
    n2 = 38820.0*holdout
    cl = 0.9
    alpha = 1-cl
    return sms.NormalIndPower().solve_power(es, nobs1=n1, alpha=alpha, ratio=n2/n1, alternative='two-sided')

holdout=np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5])
lift=np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4])

df = expand_grid({'holdout':holdout,'lift':lift})
```

The power, is basically applying the function row-wise:

```
df['power'] = df.apply(lambda x:test(x[0],x[1]),axis=1)
```

Then we plot by passing in a pivot_wide data.frame:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (13,6))
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df.pivot(index='lift',columns='holdout',values='power'),
            annot=True,cmap="inferno")
fig.axes[0].invert_yaxis()
plt
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! How would you suggest applying these functions when conversion_rate_control (0.151169) and total_group_size (38820.0) come from a pandas dataframe? So there are multiple scenarios and multiple heatmaps need to be built?

Comment: you change the function ```test``` from above to take more inputs? Then just wrap the plotting into another function.. and instead of showing it, you do https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Comment: it's like in R, you do ggsave or pdf("..")